# Resharper code annotations don't work when referencing the compiled dll

Tags: c#, resharper

Let's say I have the following class

```
public class MyClass
{
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator("propertyName")]
    public void RespondToProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        //Some code here...
    }
}
```

When another project in the solution uses this class the annotations work. Resharper does auto-complete the caller class properties (as it should).
But when I reference the compiled dll, resharper doesn't auto-complete the property names as it should.

I also tried defining the following external annotation, but no luck:

```
<assembly name=”MyAssembly">
    <member name=”M:MyAssembly.MyClass.RespondToProperty(System.String,System.String)”>
        <attribute ctor=”M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute.#ctor” />
    </member>
</assembly>
```

Can the annotation work without referencing the project code, but using only the compiled dll?

Comment: Although this does not answer your question, if you are using a somewhat recent version of .NET, you should not have to pass the caller name as string. That's just going to be a chance to introduce errors without any gain. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447549/using-string-constant-for-notify-property-changed/25447623#25447623) to see how to do this without passing the propertyname yourself as a string.

Comment: I know that. Also, I don't want it to behave like change notification. This attribute fits my needs, because I want to pass property name, but actualy it will never be the name of the "current" property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of the annotations - such as the default source implementation copied from the ReSharper 9 settings, or referencing the [official nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.Annotations/) - then they are not compiled into the resulting dll, by default.

The attributes are defined with `[Conditional("JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS")]` applied. This means that unless the `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS` symbol is defined, the attributes don't get compiled in, but ReSharper can still use the attributes for analysis. If you define `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS`, the attributes are compiled in to the resulting dll, and ReSharper will now be able to use the attributes when the resulting dll is used as a reference.

One thing to be aware of - if you're referencing the dll via the nuget package and you define `JETBRAINS_ANNOTATIONS`, then the resulting dll will now have a direct reference to JetBrains.Annotations.dll, and you'll need to ship JetBrains.Annotations.dll with your resulting dll. If you include the annotations via source, they're compiled into your resulting dll, and you don't have any extra binary references.